# PropertyNotFoundException в чем может быть причина?

Tags: java, spring, jsf

С помощью ManagedBean произвожу CRUD операции, при этом JSF кидает такую ошибку.

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /views/clients.xhtml @52,57 value="#{serviceClient.list}": Property 'list' not found on type ru.abraham.dms.services.ClientService
```

Ярко выраженных причин не обнаружил.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "serviceClient") 
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RepositoryTitles(value = RepTitle.CLIENTSERVICE)
public class ClientService implements CRUDOperationServices<ClientEntity> {      

    @Autowired
    @EntityTitle(value = Titles.CLIENTS)
    private RepositoryDAO client;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void insert(final ClientEntity object) {
        client.insert(object);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(final ClientEntity object) {
        client.update(object);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void remove(final long id) {
        client.remove(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<ClientEntity> list() {
        return client.list();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public ClientEntity objectId(final long id) {
        return (ClientEntity) client.objectId(id);
    }
}
```

Метод который падает:

```
public List<ClientEntity> list() {
    final String query = "from "
            + ClientEntity.class.getSimpleName();
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<ClientEntity> clientList = session.createQuery(query).list();
    for (ClientEntity c : clientList) {
        clientLog.info("Item:", c);
    }
    return clientList;
}
```

JSF:

```
<table class="table_data">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone number</th>
        <th>Regular</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    <ui:repeat value="#{serviceClient.list}" var="">
        <tr>
            <td>#{client.id}</td>
            <td>#{client.name}</td>
            <td>#{client.phone}</td>
            <td>#{client.regular}</td>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</table>
```

Я подозреваю что проблема из-за внедрения зависимости. `@ManagedBean` требует пустой конструктор из-за чего внедрением через конструктор пришлось пожертвовать. Читал что также что требуется сеттер, но из-за внедрения он не используется.

Comment: Попробуй использовать \@Component вместо \@ManagedBean или в JSF используй #{сlientService.list}

Comment: # я и так использую а @Component не помог

Comment: 1) выкиньте вашу реализацию запросов БД, за вас уже давно все придумали в скщностях и JPA/CRUD  реализациях 2) вы ссылаетесь на параметр/поле класса которого нет, т.е. функцию вы таким способом не вызовете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы не соблюдаете [спецификацию JavaBeans](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/). Чтобы обратиться к свойству `list` из JSF в классе бина должен быть определён как минимум метод `getList()`.

Comment: Не нужен setList, если надо получить readonly list. Не никакого желательно. Либо надо, либо нет.